# What is the proper standard for Makefiles?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm currently writing small simple C programs. As of now my Makefiles have consisted of text something along the lines of:

```
program_name:  
    clang -o program_name program_name.c
```

Is this all I need? I wasn't sure if I needed to establish dependencies between .o and .h files, even if they don't necessarily exist in my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are working too hard.  You should simplify your Makefile to 2 lines:

```
CC=clang
program_name: some.h
```

There is no need to specify the dependency on `program_name.o` or `program_name.c`, since those are implied.  There is also no need to give the rule explicitly, since you are using the default rule.  Dependencies on header files do need to be spelled out, however.

Comment: Well, it's always a good idea to explicitly specify compilation and linkage - not everyone has GNU make.

Comment: Note this kind of thing gets a LOT more complicated if you want to have portable makefiles that work on both BSD and GNU versions. Trust me, I've done it and it's an absolute pain. Also, this relies on default makefile includes(?) that usually exist, but not always.

Comment: Default rules are not gnu-make specific, but are standardized.  For simple `C` builds, any make should behave correctly.

Comment: Yes of course, I didn't say they were. I didn't know they were standardized though. I do wonder though how this handles if program_name was actually a C++ program. It's been far too long since I looked at the default rules

Answer (score 1):

I use GNU Make myself.  Not sure what you're using.  For GNU Make, refer to:

- http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Makefile-Conventions.html#Makefile-Conventions
- http://www.gnu.org/software/make/

Comment: The way you've written it, program_name will be compiled every time, whether program_name.c has changed or not.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this all I need?

No.

> I wasn't sure if I needed to establish dependencies between .o and .h files

Generally, you should, especially if you're using custom data types (and even if not: a change in a function signature can break the whole program if the ABI/calling conventions on your platform consist of black magic).

The template I'm using is usually:

```
CC = gcc
LD = $(CC)
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
LDFLAGS = -lwhatever -lfoo -lbar

TARGET = myprog
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.c: %.h

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Note: pretty sure this won't work on BSD make, if that's something that concerns you

Comment: @Earlz It does concern me. Wait a bit and I'll look it up (in the meantime, you may explain as well why).

Comment: For compatibility your best bet is to read the POSIX spec for `make` and restrict yourself to it. I'm pretty sure how you get the `OBJECTS` variable isn't valid in BSD. It's been years since I last wrote a makefile though, so I could always be wrong. If you're really curious get a free shell account at [devio.us](http://devio.us/) so you can test it on OpenBSD's version of make